# pjax not working with laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, pjax

I'm trying to setup pjax but it doesn't work. Whenever I click on a pjax link the url gets changes to `domain.com/foo` (no html content is change), then it changes to `domain.com/#` and then a normal redirect to `domain.com/foo`. Why?

This is how I trigger pjax:
`$(document).pjax('a[data-pjax]', '#wrapper');`

In my controller I have this:

```
public function getIndex() {
    $posts = $this->loginOptions();

    $this->layout->title = 'My title';      
    $content = View::make('foo.bar')
        ->with('title', $this->layout->title)
        ->with('posts', []);

    if (Request::header('X-PJAX'))
        return $content;
    else 
        $this->layout->content = $content;
}
```

My HTML (first page where I click the link) looks like this:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<html>
    <body>
    <div id='wrapper'>
        <a data-pjax href='foo'>Foobar</a>
    </div>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js'></script>
    <script src='jquery.pjax.js'></script>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I run a standard ajax call with X-PJAX header I get the correct html (that means my If is working), but the url isn't changing, which is why I want to use pjax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/login',
    type: 'get',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){ 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-PJAX', true); 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-PJAX-Container', '#wrapper') 
    },
    success: function(resp) { $('#wrapper').html(resp); }
})
```

Comment: Have you had a look at https://github.com/vtalbot/pjax?

Comment: I've tested that and https://github.com/simonstamm/laravel-pjax and I have the same issue with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up on [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax). I'm now using [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) instead.

Javascript:

```
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){
    var State = History.getState();
    $.ajax({
        url: State.url,
        type: 'get',
        beforeSend: function(xhr){ 
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-PJAX', true); 
        },
        success: function(resp, status, xhr) { 
            document.title = xhr.getResponseHeader('Page-Title');
            $('#wrapper').html(resp); 
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('click', 'a[data-pjax]', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var self = $(this);

    History.pushState(null, 'Loading page...', self.attr('href'));
});
```

PHP (controller):

```
public function getIndex() {
    $this->layout->title = 'My Title';      
    $content = View::make('my.view')
        ->with('title', $this->layout->title)
        ->with('posts', []);

    if (Request::header('X-PJAX')) {
        return Response::make($content)
            ->header('Page-Title', $this->layout->title);
    } else 
        $this->layout->content = $content;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You were so close :D

JS:

```
$(document).pjax('a[data-pjax]', '#wrapper', { fragment: '#wrapper});
```

The change to # with a consequent reload happens because the pjax works, but does not find a HTML element with the id #wrapper, so it runs into timeout and reloads the page. This behavior is wanted, because older browser(with no pushstate/popstate/ajax support) then load all links like the page was static.

Try changing this:

```
 if (Request::header('X-PJAX'))
        echo '<div id="wrapper"> pjaxxx </div>';
    else 
        $this->layout->content = $content;
```

I know you already solved this problem using history.js, but pjax solves the stupid hashbanging and is quiet easy to use once implemented.

Hope you still read this, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I've just started using Rob Crowe's Turbo...

https://github.com/rcrowe/Turbo

works like a charm

(uses pjax under the hood)